# Pasar select/option a variable

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

finalmente me decidí a hacer la consulta en un foro, puesto que ya no encuentro una forma de solucionar la duda que tengo.

Estoy intentando pasar la opcion elegida de un select/option hacia unos campos que se encuentran ocultos y que sean autocompletados.

He leido bastante, y he pasado tanto por JS como por AJAX y php, sin embargo no consigo hacer que me funcione. el Caso es este.

Actualmente tengo esto:

```
 <td><select  class="form-control2" name="origen" id="idorigen">
    <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
        <?php
        while($dato = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$dato['db_nombre'].'"> '.$dato['db_nombre'].' </option>';
        }
        ?>
        </select> </td> 
        <button onclick="mostrar()">Buscar</button>

<div id="flotante" style="display:none;" class="row"  value="idorigen">
<?php
?>
<input type=text class="form-control2" id="valueanterior" value="">
</div>



<script languague="javascript">
    function mostrar() {
        var e = document.getElementById("idorigen");

        var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;


       document.getElementById("valueanterior").value = value;


        div = document.getElementById('flotante');
        div.style.display = '';


    }

    function cerrar() {
        div = document.getElementById('flotante');
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

Esto me muestra la opcion elegida como id=valueanterior. Sin embargo en el div flotante, necesito tener la variable valueanterior para poder realizar una consulta mysql y obtener los datos de usuario, password, servidor, etc usando dicha variable.

No he encontrado el modo de hacerlo o bien una mejor forma. Intente usar Post, sin embargo al usar post, la pagina se refresca y el div flotante desaparece, aparece solo al momento de hacer presionar buscar, luego recarga la pagina y desaparece, por esta razon no me funciona.
Si alguien puede darme una mano seria genial. Perdon si no esta bien explicado, es la primera vez que escribo en un foro y la verdad no me manejo mucho.
Gracias y saludos

Comment: debes usar ajax, para ello debes publicar lo que has intentado hasta ahora con ajax.

Comment: Pon el codigo completo no sabemos de donde viene $dato, ni si $sql esta bien formado etc... Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

No entendi bien tu redacción amigo, pero quizás te sirva el evento onChange,
agregué ese evento a tu código, que ejecuta una funcion (muy básica, puede generalizarse de muchas otras formas) que insertará la seleccion en el elemento con id que elijas.

```js
function mostrar() {
        var e = document.getElementById("idorigen");

        var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;


       document.getElementById("valueanterior").value = value;


        div = document.getElementById('flotante');
        div.style.display = '';


    }

    function cerrar() {
        div = document.getElementById('flotante');
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
    
    function insertData(elementChanged,elementId){
      document.getElementById(elementId).value = elementChanged.value;
    }
```

```html
<td><select  class="form-control2" name="origen" id="idorigen" onChange='insertData(this,"valueanterior")'>
    <option selected disabled>Seleccione</option>
    <option value="dato1">dato1</option>
    <option value="dato2">dato2</option>
        </select> </td> 
        <button onclick="mostrar()">Buscar</button>

<div id="flotante" class="row"  value="idorigen">
<input type=text class="form-control2" id="valueanterior" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, sin embargo utilice ajax como me comentaban mas arriba y funciono perfecto.
Muy agradecido

Answer (score 0):

partiendo de tu select podrias usar el evento onchange:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_id" onchange="miFuncion($(this).val());">
<option selected disabled>seleccione:</option>
<option value="valor_1">opcion 1</option>
<option value="valor_2">opcion 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="valor_select">
<script>
function miFuncion(select_id){
$("#valor_select").val(select_id);
}
</script>
```

en este caso uso Jquery
te dejo el link donde lo probe :[link](https://jsfiddle.net/kgohquuf/)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!, lo que tengo es similar, si te fijas paso valueanterior como id, y lo despliego en el input como id=valueanterior. En mi caso necesito ese valor como una variable no como un id, puesto que debo utilizarlo.

Algo como $valor = "valor_select" para poder usar luego esa variable en otra consulta mysql. No se si se entiende... El link que dejaste no funciona

Comment: ese es el link https://jsfiddle.net/kgohquuf/ y una vez que obtienes el id o valor del select puedes hacer lo que deseas psar a un php y luego con eso hacer tu consulta

Comment: @Lusagsilva esta sería la mejor forma de hacerlo. El problema es que te estás planteando una solución complicada... hablas de mantener el valor en un div oculto o flotante o algo así... nada de eso es necesario si tú usas Ajax. Por ejemplo aquí, tú puedes ejecutar una petición Ajax desde `miFuncion`, enviando al servidor el valor recuperado (`select_id`). La petición Ajax haría la consulta y te devolvería los resultados ¡y además si tener que refrescar la página!. Como ves, es mucho más simple de lo que crees. ¡Ajax es la clave!

Comment: [Aquí tienes un ejemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/6fju-td04) pulsa en **`Run - F9`** para verlo funcionando. Al hacer click en el botón, se manda al servidor el valor del id escrito en el input box y el servidor busca los datos de la persona en base a ese valor y te los devuelve. Con esos datos devueltos por el servidor, se llenan los campos del formulario. Todo eso se hace en background, sin tener que moverte de la página. Incluso, puedes cambiar de id, y consultar datos de otra persona, siempre sin moverte de la página.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos!, como decia @A.Cedano la clave fue AJAX.

No sabia muy bien como hacerlo y simplemente cree un getdata.php donde almacenaba la consulta y la retornaba con JSON.
Fue la solucion que me funciono, simple y efectivamente. 
Muchas gracias a todos